# Consuming sharded database using node.js

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express.js

I think the only big improvement that can be made is to check which shard to query based on the `userId`s of the followed users. One easy way is to check the last number of each `userId` (0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9) and then find which shard I need to query if I have 10.

Besides that is there anything wrong?

I am wondering if it makes sense to call the shards in a `for` loop, or there's a way to call it once and let it get handled by a library.

```js
const express = require('express');
const mysql = require('mysql2/promise');

const app = express();
const port = 3000;

// Replace with your actual database connection details
const shardConfigs = [
  {
    host: 'shard1_host',
    user: 'shard1_user',
    password: 'shard1_password',
    database: 'shard1_database',
  },
  {
    host: 'shard2_host',
    user: 'shard2_user',
    password: 'shard2_password',
    database: 'shard2_database',
  },
  // Add configurations for other shards as needed
];

// Create connections for each shard
const shardConnections = shardConfigs.map(config => mysql.createConnection(config));

app.get('/user/feed/:userId', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const userId = req.params.userId;

    // Step 1: Identify Sharded Database Shard (Hash-based Strategy)
    const selectedShardIndex = userId % shardConfigs.length;
    const selectedShardConnection = shardConnections[selectedShardIndex];

    // Step 2: Query User's Followings
    const followingQuery = 'SELECT followed_user_id FROM followers WHERE follower_user_id = ?';
    const [followingRows] = await selectedShardConnection.execute(followingQuery, [userId]);
    const followingUsers = followingRows.map(row => row.followed_user_id);

    // Step 3: Retrieve Tweets from Followed Users
    const tweets = [];
    for (const shardConnection of shardConnections) {
      const tweetsQuery = 'SELECT * FROM tweets WHERE user_id IN (?) ORDER BY timestamp DESC';
      const [shardTweets] = await shardConnection.execute(tweetsQuery, [followingUsers]);
      tweets.push(...shardTweets);
    }

    // Step 4: Sort and Combine Tweets
    const combinedTweets = tweets.sort((a, b) => b.timestamp - a.timestamp);

    // Step 5: Limit and Paginate
    // Add logic here to limit the number of tweets returned, implement pagination if needed

    // Step 6: Return the Feed to the User Interface
    const feedData = combinedTweets.map(tweet => ({
      tweet_id: tweet.tweet_id,
      user_id: tweet.user_id,
      content: tweet.content,
    }));

    res.json({ feed: feedData });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    res.status(500).json({ error: 'Internal Server Error' });
  }
});

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running at http://localhost:${port}`);
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using `mysql.createConnection(config)` inside a `map` function which is synchronous while `mysql.createConnection` is asynchronous and returns a Promise thus you might end up with a `Promise` object instead of a connection object in `shardConnections`. You should await these connections inside an async function before starting your server.

```
async function initShardConnections() {
  for (let i = 0; i < shardConfigs.length; i++) {
    shardConnections[i] = await mysql.createConnection(shardConfigs[i]);
  }
}

// Call this function before starting your server
initShardConnections().then(() => {
  app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server is running at http://localhost:${port}`);
  });
});
```

Querying each shard in a loop is not the best way, as it does not utilize the potential for parallel queries. A better approach is to initiate all shard queries simultaneously using `Promise.all` and then combine the results thus your queries will run in parallel, reducing the overall response time.

```
const tweetPromises = shardConnections.map(shardConnection =>
  shardConnection.execute(tweetsQuery, [followingUsers])
);
const results = await Promise.all(tweetPromises);
const tweets = results.flatMap(result => result[0]);
```